# How can I disable clicking sound for Action Menu button?

Tags: android

Seems straight forward, but I can't find in the documentation how to disable the sound (water drop sound) that plays when I click a button.

The reason this is important, is that the button records audio. And when you play back the audio, you can hear the button clicking.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using this attribute in xml:

```
android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
```

Or in code by:

```
btn.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
```